# IndexError when printing with readlines()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep encountering an index error when trying to print a line from a text file. I'm new to python and I'm still trying to learn so I'd appreciate if you can try to be patient with me; if there is something else needed from me, please let me know!

The traceback reads as

```
...
    print(f2.readlines()[1]):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

When trying to print line 2 (`...[1]`), I am getting this out of range error.

Here's the current script.

```
with open("f2.txt", "r") as f2:
    print(f2.readlines()[1])
```

There are 3 lines with text in the file.

contents of f2.txt

```
peaqwenasd
lasnebsat
kikaswmors
```

Comment: You have a missing colon at the end of the first line; I'm not sure how this executes at all.  When I supply the colon and give it a non-empty file, it works just fine, printing the file's second line.

Comment: Oops! fixed the colon. I am unsure why I am getting the error if it works fine for you? Any ideas

Comment: No idea; I don't have any way to reproduce the error.  `f2.txt` might contain a clue, but you didn't provide the expected [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: No problem @Prune! I'll add that as an edit.

Comment: Nope ... works fine for me.  Try pasting this input into a new `f2.txt` file.  Try separating the read and print operations: read into a variable; print the variable and its length.

Comment: @Dansey why does this post have a PRAW tag? Nothing about this seems related to [the Python Reddit API Wrapper](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: @jarhill0 -- good point.  I removed it.

Comment: @jarhill0 must've been a mistake as I've been working in PRAW lately for the code.

Comment: Will try that @Prune, thank you.

Comment: @Prune oddly enough, `print(f2.readlines()[1])` seems to be working yet `print(f2.readlines()[2])` returns the out of range index error. Edit, also seems that `f2.seek(0)` in between reads solves that issue...

Comment: @Dansey: I'm guessing you called `readlines` multiple times, yet left it out of your actual question. That's kind of important.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `f2.seek(0)` was necessary here to solve the issue.

```
with open("f2.txt", "r") as f2:
    f2.seek(0)
    print(f2.readlines()[1])
```

Comment: This isn't particularly efficient.  You're re-reading the entire file each time you want to access a single line.  See my answer for alternatives.  Better yet, work through a couple of tutorials on reading from a text file.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given all the code needed to solve your problem, but your given symptoms point to multiple calls to `readlines`.

Read the documentation: `readlines()` reads the entire file and returns a list of the contents.  As a consequence, the file pointer is at the end of the file.  If you call `readlines()` again at this point, it returns an empty file.

You apparently have a `readlines()` call before the code you gave us.  `seek(0)` resets the file pointer to the start of the file, and you're reading the entire file a second time.

There are many tutorials that show you canonical ways to iterate through the contents of a file.  I strongly recommend that you use one of those.  For instance:

```
with open("f2.txt", "r") as f2:
    for line in f2.readlines():
        # Here you can work with the lines in sequence
```

If you need to deal with the lines in non-sequential order, then

```
with open("f2.txt", "r") as f2:
    content = list(f2.readlines())
    # Now you can access content[2], content[1], etc.
```

Comment: Thanks Prune! Is there any benefits to using these over my current solution? Would using a variable like you have remove the need for `.seek()`

Comment: @Dansey  If you want us to help with the problem, you have to give us proper code.  Again, we need that MCVE.  Follow the posting guidelines for which we gave links.